# Custom LI format in HTML?

Tags: html

I want to display list items with a prefix, like:

```
  ML-1. ..........................
        ...................
  ML-2. ........
  ML-3. ...................
        ............
ML-100. .........................
        ............
```

Is it possible? I tried to use `li:before { content: "ML-" counter(item) ". "; }` however it seems like not supported well in many browsers. And I can't make the numbers right aligned.

Comment: Both `:before` and `content: counter` are supported pretty widely; it's only IE7 and below that should have an issue with either of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that isn't possible.  Your best bet would be to use a blank-styled unordered list and put the prefix in the body of each LI.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with jQuery. Unless you don't want to have it on the page?
Or if you provide a little more details on how you populate the list i could suggest something else

Comment: Well, it's just written in the plain html page.

Comment: if it's written and is not populated dynamically, you could use Find/Replace to add leading content, unless i'm missing something